# c++ O3 optimization breaks working while loop

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-optimization, fseek

I have this simple code that searches the file for "data" step by step using fseek in a pcm wav file:

```
  FILE * waveFile;
  waveFile = fopen ( this->fileLocation.c_str ( ), "rb" );

  // ... some other code here between, then ... //

  int seekTo = 0;
  bool found = false;
  char data[4];

  rewind ( waveFile );
  while ( !found && ( fseek ( waveFile, seekTo, SEEK_SET ) == 0 )) {
    fread ( data, sizeof ( data ), 1, waveFile );
    if (( std::strcmp ( data, "data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "Data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "DATA" ) == 0 )) {
      found = true;
      fread ( &waveHeader->DATA_SIZE, sizeof ( waveHeader->DATA_SIZE ), 1, waveFile );
    }
    seekTo++;
  }
```

The code works correctly, and on test files it finds the data, reads the remaining. As the "data" is near to the beginning on even the biggest files, this code is ok for me.

But, when I add the cpp flag -O3, code goes haywire, while loop never finishes.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3")
```

I'm using cmake + lldb (osx, clion), same thing happens if I use GDB.

What can be the problem, how can I resolve this?

PS. I'm not trying to improve the code you see, I'm trying to understand why compiler optimization hacks this while loop.

PSS.
Here is the null terminated working code:

```
  int seekTo = 0;
  char data[5];

  rewind ( waveFile );
  while (( fseek ( waveFile, seekTo, SEEK_SET ) == 0 )) {
    fread ( data, 4, 1, waveFile );
    data[ 4 ] = '\0';

    if (( std::strcmp ( data, "data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "Data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "DATA" ) == 0 )) {
      fread ( &waveHeader->DATA_SIZE, sizeof ( waveHeader->DATA_SIZE ), 1, waveFile );
      break;
    }
    seekTo += 1;
  }
```

Comment: `std::strcmp ( data, "data" ) == 0` reads out of bounds of `data`. You're forgetting about null termination. Maybe you want to `memcmp` with length `4`.

Comment: You should also check whether `fread` succeeded and break the loop if it failed

Comment: @M.M i originally have the size_t check for fread in the code and it returns 0 in some point. But in every file I have has "data" in it, and file end is reached before finding anything. so I removed the end check for debugging.

Comment: that doesn't make much sense, if you do read off the end then you risk undefined behaviour  . Also maybe you want to break out (or advance by several bytes) when you do find "Data".

Comment: if things break at -O3 it means your code has bugs. You should find the bug rather than making random changes (that are most likely just to make the bug's effect show up somewhere else).  If your memset wrote out of bounds then it shouldn't be in there at any optimization level, and if it did not write out of bounds then presumably you had some reason for writing it, dictated by your program logic, and that wouldn't change based on optimization level either.

Comment: @M.M :) I get that, what i'm trying to understand why this code works without any optimization enabled, and finds the string correctly.

Comment: You got lucky (or unlucky) depending on how to view it, your code reads (and perhaps writes) out of bounds of arrays and it just depends on what happened to be in that memory and whether the optimizer excised any code blocks that it detected would access out of bounds and so on. You can't get any more detailed answer than that other than by inspecting the assembly code that your compiler generated for the code.

Comment: Your strcmp call is illegal. You just got "lucky" that it didn't fail at other optimization levels. Fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody else wants to write an answer... When code works with optimizations off but stops working with optimizations on, it's likely some undefined behavior that's revealed by a compiler optimization. In your case that bug is:

```
char data[4];
...
fread ( data, sizeof ( data ), 1, waveFile );
if (( std::strcmp ( data, "data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "Data" ) == 0 ) || ( std::strcmp ( data, "DATA" ) == 0 )) {
```

[`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is for:

> Compares two **null-terminated** byte strings lexicographically.

So either `data` happens to have a `\0` in it somewhere, and the comparison is false (because `data` would be too short). Or it doesn't, and you're going to read way off the end of `data` toward some random null byte in memory. As a result, the compiler could deduce that there's *no way* that comparison could be true and optimize your code into:

```
if (false) { ... }
```

and then drop the `if` statement completely.

Perhaps in the non-optimized build, you happened to always have zero memory immediately after `data` and the `if` was never optimized out?

---

An easy fix for this would be to ensure that `data` is null-terminated:

```
char data[5];
data[4] = '\0';
// rest as before
```

Or to replace your calls of `strcmp` to `memcmp`, providing `sizeof(data)` as the additional length argument.

Comment: thanks for understanding the underlying question :) 

what i can see in debugging that with optimizations, char[] array gets a few extra characters at the end and size is wrong, but this does not happen in other case. however, the program continues to read the file.

that's all I needed. I already have the null terminated corrected version, working fine in -o3. but I wondered why it was working correctly without optimizations.

Comment: It wasn't working correctly without optimizations. It shows undefined behavior both with optimizations on AND off. Undefined behavior can include things like making demons fly out of your nose, send a resignation letter to your next boss _but most scary of ALL can happen to do exactly what you wanted_. Which is what you're were getting with optimizations disabled. Without optimizations, it was still broken but happened to work and may've stopped working at anytime.

Answer (score 2):

strcmp is a string comparison function compares the strings until the NUL character is found. You are using a char[4] for your string, so there is no space for the NUL character. The fact that this worked was an accident.

In your case you are probably better off using memcpy for 4 bytes.